# Is there a limit to the complexity of indefinite integrals that Matlab can solve?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate expressions for magnetic helicity rate of change in Matlab, where the overall formula I am calculating is:

int(A * B * V,x)

(the topic itself isn't really necessary here).

B is essentially a constant multiplied by the legendre polynomials of degree 0-9 and order 0.

B is the curl of A so A is then found by Stokes' Theorem, and V is a function of x which is always the same.

When I run the script below, dH only has an explicit answer for the i=1 case, all other cases for dH are left as int(A(i)*B(i)*V,x). So my question is, are the expressions that I'm trying to integrate simply too complicated for matlab of have I done something wrong in the code? (Note, g and R are constants)

Thanks for your help!

```
%%Calculate B, A and dh/dt expressions for m=0 case
clear
syms x %In our case this is theta 
syms R
syms g
syms a
syms b
syms c

V = a + b*cos(x)^2 + c*cos(x)^4;

for i = 1:10 %Matlab indices must start from 1

    B(i) = g*legendreP(i-1,x);

    A(i) = R*csc(x)*int(sin(x)*B(i),0,x);

    dH(i) = int(A(i)*B(i)*V,x);

end
```

Comment: What is your goal doing this symbolically? There is likely no analytical solution involving basic functions for the higher orders. There are solutions involving complex-valued [polylogarithms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html)  – see [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral%5B(R*g%5E2*x*(sin(x)+-+x*cos(x))*(c*cos(x)%5E4+%2B+b*cos(x)%5E2+%2B+a))%2Fsin(x),x%5D) (probably Mathematica too) – but I'm not sure how that will be helpful.

Comment: To be honest I will be computing it for different latitudes theta so I could just put the limits in and get a value out. However, I just wondered why it didn't give expressions symbolically